# Not rounding properly

Tags: c#, rounding

```
Math.Round(keyRate, 5).ToString("N5")
```

If keyRate is a number like 3.7066666666, you will see 3.70666 rather than 3.70667

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Interesting... according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy06z30k.aspx , it should not work that way.

Comment: What type is `keyRate`? I've just tried your code with `float`, `double` and `decimal`, and all of them produced 3.70667.

Comment: Hmmm ... did you get 3.70666 ?

Comment: @herbal - yes that's what we got

Comment: Works fine for me: `Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(3.7066666666,5)); //3.70667`
`Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(3.7066666666, 5).ToString("N5")); // 3.70667`

Comment: Hmmm, idk then. This is really weird

Comment: @slandu: what datatype is your variable?

Comment: Hmmm... I get the [proper value](http://ideone.com/0NLM8).

Comment: which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: .net 4.0 right now, although that has been the code since we weren't on 4.0 yet

Comment: That's impossible! Provide your code, somewhere else is wrong!

Comment: i know right? somewhere else has to be doing something behind the scenes that i just havent dug into yet

Comment: @slandau: *keyRate* is a calculation result instead of direct assigned value in your code, right?

Comment: yup. no direct assignment, comes back from calc

Comment: @slandau: So you need to provide the code that calculates the value. Or you can re-assign the value directly before output, to prove `Math.Round`/`ToString` is not the reason for the unexpected result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Math.Round function used what's called banker's rounding by default.  Banker's rounding rounds toward the even number.  To get the more traditional type of rounding, call the Round method like this:

```
Math.Round(3.7066666666, 5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

correction: After looking again at @slandau's number I realized that banker's rounding isn't the issue here.  Banker's rounding only applies when the fractional portion of the number to the right of the desired precision is exactly halfway between two values.  In other words

```
Math.Round(3.7066650000, 5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) = 3.70667
```

while the following (Banker's rounding)

```
Math.Round(3.7066650000, 5, MidpointRounding.ToEven) = 3.70666
```

@slandau's result should be 3.70667 either way.

Comment: So *3.70666* is an even number while *3.70667* is odd?

Comment: The final 6 is even.  If you were rounding to whole numbers, it would round to 4.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even

Comment: I think *even* and *odd* are modifiers for integers.

Comment: It's the number at the position being rounded to that determines even or odd, so yes, 3.70666 is even based on the last 6.

Comment: The concepts of *even* / *odd* begins with integers. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odd_number). The question is irrelative with banker's rounding.

Answer (score -1):

You should use decimal and `Math.Round(keyRate, 5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)`
It isn't work with double